# Https is not working properly. Few pages are not working with https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I need a guidance to fix the issue. The issue is https redirection. I have site called 'https://clipcanvas.com/'. On the site some of the pages are working with https as i expect. But Some of the pages like Homepage, and some other pages are only working with http. Not with https? I dont why. I tried alot to solve this.

Please help me. I will post my all codes of .htaccess file here:

```
Satisfy any

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clipcanvas\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.clipcanvas.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am using zendframework. Please help me. If you need any clarification please ping here.

Comment: https://www.clipcanvas.com/ redirects to the HTTP version. Presumably you have some other redirects happening somewhere - is there anything else in your htaccess file that does redirects?

Comment: zf has nothing about it. its your htaccess. checkout @Ben's answer